# Veracrypt The device is not ready

Tags: veracrypt

My System (Windows 8 running in VirtualBox)  shutdowned unexpectedly. When I restarted the system Veracypt wouldn't start saying. "The device is not ready. Source: Mounted:4743"

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the system seem to have solved the problem

Comment: Some say the mountvol /E command before rebooting helps. I seemed to have this problem after using diskmgmt.msc to hide a drive letter, at least before rebooting. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2019/01/11/veracrypt-error-8257/

Comment: P.S. In my version of this problem, it was "MountVolume:8292" and "MountVolume:8257."